# Extract just first line of pdf in python

Tags: python, pdf, readline

I have a pdf document that is 2 pages.
I am running a loop where I am reading multipe pdf files and
I just want to extract the first line and print it as I want to store the date from the file.
When using the following code:

```
import pdfplumber
pdf = pdfplumber.open("mypdf.pdf")
page = pdf.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
print(text[0:10])
```

I am able to get the date for my first document using that line of code, but depending on the date, it will also capture the second line.
When I use the code print(test[0:]) it prints all the lines.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try breaking it by '\n', and then use subscripting to grab the first item.

Comment: Break the text by using `text.split("\n")[0]`. That will return the first line.